# how do I guide pabot to find my custom libraries or APIs?

Tags: python, robotframework, pyinstaller, exe, pythonpath

I am using Pabot of Robot Framework. I have created a whole application that in background runs the Robot Framework.

This exe understands the path which I mentioned during pyinstaller. So it opens up fine without needing of the source code.

Now, when code reaches to this pabot command, Which I am using programmatically as follows:

```
pabot_command = ["pabot", "--testlevelsplit", "-d", abs_result, abs_filepath]
result = subprocess.run(pabot_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)

# Check if the command executed successfully
if result.returncode == 0:
    for line in result.stdout.split('\n'):
         print(line)
         print("--------------xxx--------------xxx--------------xxx--------------")
else:
    print(f"Error executing the command... {result.stderr}")
```

it complains about not finding the modules which I am using via Resource file.

When I keep the exe in the same folder of the source code, it does find those modules.

I know there's a method in robot package robot.run() in which user can mention --PYTHONPATH like this. But when pabot doesn't have that.

so is there any solution for pabot